# in python sys.argv doesn't print rounded parentheses

Tags: php, python

I have a stupid problem but I can't solve it. I have to run a python script from php and I use this command:

```
$output=shell_exec("python/Users/leonardo/Sites/ema/server/sqlConnector.py. $user." ".$pass." 2>&1");
```

but in python, if I do:

```
print sys.argv
```

It seems to have no effect if one of the two parameters has a round parenthesis. if I delete the parentheses, the command is executed

**For exemple**

```
$output=shell_exec("python/Users/leonardo/Sites/ema/server/sqlConnector.py myname password 2>&1");

#print
['"python/Users/leonardo/Sites/ema/server/sqlConnector.py myname password 2>&1"', 'myname', 'password']
```

but

```
$output=shell_exec("python/Users/leonardo/Sites/ema/server/sqlConnector.py myname pass(word) 2>&1");

#doesn't print anything
```

Comment: Parentheses have special meaning in the shell, they need to be quoted or escaped.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `sys.argv`, it's being done by the shell. Try just typing `echo pass(word)` in the shell.

Comment: Sorry. I'm a beginner .___. . But now it's works. Thanks everybody

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape you arguments with [`escapeshellarg()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.escapeshellarg.php)

```php
$user = escapeshellarg($user);
$pass = escapeshellarg($pass);
$output=shell_exec("python/Users/leonardo/Sites/ema/server/sqlConnector.py $user $pass 2>&1");
```